# SQLite Assembly Error in VS 2010

Tags: sqlite

I'm *trying* to develop a settings application whererby a developer can download a zip file containing a SQLite database and the relevant DLL's and simple use it by calling Setting.Set and Setting.Get in their code.  Using a simple Key/Value pair in the database, this lets users store any setting, for anything.

However, I keep getting the error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

...when trying to integrate it into a new test app.

I've tried the

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

section in the App.config but this doesn't fix the problem.

I'm trying to make the "plug-in" as easy as possible for the end user/developer for re-usability but this is becoming very tedious indeed! >:-(

Any ideas guys?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using the latest System.Data.SQLite assembly:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Somewhere on that page you'll find "Precompiled Statically-Linked Binaries for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)" which should be fine for packaging the System.Data.SQLite assembly with your app.

This should also allow you to not use the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"` application setting.